# Scraping user comments in Scrapy - Where is site getting data from?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Could anybody tell me how to use Scrapy to grab the text of the users comments from [this page](https://www.guancha.cn/internation/2020_01_30_533668.shtml)? I understand how to use the selectors to retrieve items from the scraped code, but the page seems to be drawing the data for the comments from somewhere else. I can't work out where.

I've tried inspecting the site using site inspector and 'Network' tab in Chrome. I thought it might be 'https://user.guancha.cn/static/js/comments-plugin-cms.js?201910221652' but I can't see the comments stored there.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments for this article are coming from this request: https://user.guancha.cn/comment/cmt-list.json?codeId=440605&codeType=1&pageNo=1&order=1&ff=www

Here you can see some important variables: codeId (which is some kind of articleid, this number is being set on article's page, you can see it in page's source) and cursor for paginating - pageNo.

So, you just need to get codeId for interested article and crawl all comments for it from this endpoint (cmt-list.json). Response is json, so it's easy to parse comment's data.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed. Do you mind telling me how you found out that was the url (that way I can learn for next time).

Comment: You can use Developer tools in your browser  Press F12 in your browser (chrome or firefox in common), switch to "Network Tab" . After reloading page we can see all requests our browser made. Especially we're interested in XHR requested (they can be filtered on network tab). XHR - requests issued by javascript, that appends code to DOM.